How to Connect Group Connect and how fields and LINE id are attributed?
I'm new to Group Connect and we're thinking of implementing the solution for asian countries, however I'm bite confused.
For the Mobile Connect for example for SMS we have Phone Field or we can link the Phone field in Journey settings, this way we can know how to send the SMS to a certain contact with a specifi Phone Number. But in Group Connect how is that is done ? which field will have the LINE ID to know which person will receive the message ?
Also, we have Salesforce Sales cloud and we're linking it to SFMC with Connector, so in Journey Level for example, Subscriber key will be ? LINE ID ?
Also what Sorts of Limitations Group Connect have compared to maybe some customized solutions ?
Any help and reply to my questions would be much appreciated!

There's a lot to cover with LINE channel enablement and messaging part.
GroupConnect messaging is done through LINE Address ID, which is unique per follower, similar to an Email Address or Phone number.
Normally, the default integration between LINE and SFMC is only half of the solution.
(The other half is a more complex solution which I will not cover further)
The reason is that every new LINE follower to the connected LINE channel will automatically create a new Contact in Marketing Cloud with a LINE specific ID which becomes their ContactKey. This new Contact has the LINE subscription as opt-in.
It could very well be that this follower is already an existing client or prospect in Salesforce CRM, which means they probably also exist in Marketing Cloud with a Salesforce ID. This means you will have a duplicate billable Contact in SFMC for such people.
Therefore with only SMFC-LINE integration you are forced to use the LINE generated ID's as your ContactKeys for all LINE messaging activities.

Right, I have understood that line is done via LINE Address ID, but generated Follower ID, can't we have like a list of contacts, let's say in a file that can be imported into the system ?
